# .htaccess Redirect subdomain to domain using condition

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my site was builded do use `subdomains.domain.com` now I want to redirect all `subdomain.domain.com` to `domain.com` how i do this in htaccess

now if a user come to `anysubdomain.domain.com` to redirect him to `domain.com`
this is what i have now and it is working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
ErrorDocument 400 /index.php
ErrorDocument 401 /index.php
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
ErrorDocument 500 /index.php
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @anubhava - no cos i dont know what to try :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: dose nothing i replaced domain with my domain

Comment: Is this first rule in .htaccess? What is location of this .htaccess?

Comment: DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess

Comment: Is that `DOCUMENT_ROOT` for subdomain also?

Comment: it is in root and it's everything i have now on htaccess

Comment: also .. one more i have if now i have domain . com/anything.html i want to redirect to domain . com what do i write .. it is different site dosen't have to do anything with previous one

Comment: So you want `domain.com/anything.html => domain.com`?

Comment: It's something that I changed on website before was domain.com/product.html and now i changed it to domain.com/product-detail1-detail2.html and if it goes to domain.com/product.html when he browse next product .. i generated in database a slug.. so the new details are getting from the slug i generated when i entered products in db .. so now .. when he goes from domain.com/product-detail1-detail2.html .. using your rule .. it's sending him to root of the site ..

Comment: so .. to be more clear .. what i want now is domain.com/product.html to goest to domain.com/new-product-url.html

Comment: this is what i have now `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]`

Comment: I'm thoroughly confused now with these new requirements. I would suggest creating a new question with clear set of requirements.